# Can't resolve org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.JDOCursorHelper in DataNucleus jars supplied with appengine java sdk

Tags: java, google-app-engine, orm

I am using query cursors in my appengine java application as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Query_Cursors

I have added all the required jars to my WEB-INF/lib as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2#Copying_the_JARs

But the code doesn't compile because org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.JDOCursorHelper can't be resolved

Here's a screenshot of my WEB-INF/lib directory:

[image]

Do I need to add some other jars? Which ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JDOCursorHelper` is present in `datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar` as

```
com/google/appengine/datanucleus/query/JDOCursorHelper
```

It is Google's code and nothing to do with the [DataNucleus project](http://www.datanucleus.org).